# Wordpress search failed on special characters due to improper decode

Tags: php, string, wordpress, special-characters, decode

I am implementing the Wordpress search functionality.
When I search for text "**Division's**" (which is a text in one of the posts),
It returns "No results found"

Now to investigate further, I checked the core file: 
**wp-includes/query.php => function parse_search()**

And found that the $term is received encoded as : **Division\xe2\x80\x99s**

Now this term is not decoded properly. And the final SQL statement formed is : 
(((test_posts.post_title LIKE '%Division\xe2\x80\x99s%') OR (test_posts.post_content LIKE '%Division\xe2\x80\x99s%')))

So, I want to decode the special characters to succesfully search terms with special characters too.

Decoding methods like :

- $string = urldecode($string);
- $string = html_entity_decode($string);
- $string = rawurldecode ($string);
- $string = base64_decode($string);
- $string = utf8_decode($string);

Did not work.
Is there any plugin/hook/method that can help?

***Example Provided:***

Simple `searchform.php` file here:

```
if (!defined('ABSPATH')) exit(0); 

global $wp_query;

$search_query = get_search_query();
$error = get_query_var('error'); ?>

<form role="search" method="get" class="search-form form-inline" action="<?php echo esc_url(home_url('/')); ?>">
    <input id="mod-search-searchword" type="search" size="30" class="inputbox search-query search-field" placeholder="search products, content" value="<?php echo !empty($search_query) && empty($error) ? $search_query : ''; ?>" name="s" title="Search for:" />
    <input type="submit" class="button btn btn-primary" value="Search" />
</form>
```

Now if I type in characters like `()` they get urlencoded, and that same urlencoded string not populates into the text field with the percentages, etc.

If I do this:

```
$search_query = !empty($search_query) ? trim(sanitize_text_field(urldecode($search_query))) : '';
```

There is still a problem, but no longer a problem with the text input not having correct string, the problem becomes that there are no search results now.

How to fix this issue with Wordpress Search?

wp-config.php contains the following:

```
define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');
```

header.php contains the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=3.0, user-scalable=yes"/>
        <meta name="HandheldFriendly" content="true" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="YES" />
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/favicon.ico" type="image/vnd.microsoft.icon" />
        <title><?php wp_title(' - ', true, 'right'); ?></title>
        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
```

I have the following in my functions.php file:

```
function livchem_searchfilter($query) {

    global $search_query;

    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {

        // check if length of query > 3 but < 200
        $search_query = trim(get_search_query());
        $search_length = strlen($search_query);

        if ($search_length < 3 || $search_length > 200)
        {
            $query->set('error', 'Search term must be a minimum of 3 characters and a maximum of 200 characters.');
            return $query;
        }
        else
        {
            $query->set('post_type', array('post', 'page', 'product'));
            $query->set('posts_per_page', 20);
        }
    }

    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','livchem_searchfilter');
```

So, I do have UTF-8 encoding as my charset afaik.  What is the problem, why is my search for: `copper(i)/(ii)` returning `?s=copper%2528i%2529%252F%2528ii%2529` in the URL?  And I should have 2 results found for this, but I get 0 results found.  Why?

And if I change the url to this:  `?s=copper(i)/(ii)` I see my 2 results.  But why can't I get my results, and/or the url to be like this?  I could honestly care less on what the url structure is, but I do want my 2 results to be found when I type in:  `copper(i)/(ii)` into the search form, but currently it is not finding any results.

Comment: it is not about encoding, its about charsets, use [utf8](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: I stumbled upon this and am not in front of a clean wordpress install. Some details you should add to your question include, are you using a custom post type or to the best of your knowledge was this a default post type. As far as my knowledge wordpress only searches post titles, tags, and categories and not the post body (I may be wrong on this but I feel like I had a similar issue with search results and figured this out via one of the core files). As @Lashane pointed out UTF-8 is probably the answer if this is a custom thing.

Comment: Can you please provide the term as it appears in the database? That way we can compare it to the one we are searching for and see if they are the same.

Comment: wp-config.php has the following:  `define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8');
define('DB_COLLATE', '');`  So, I am using ut8 as the charset here.

Answer (score 10):

Ok, so you do have to decode the search query and here's how I have it working and works like a charm now!  This now returns the search results, but keeps the url encoded so no problems anywhere here.

```
function livchem_search_filter($s) {
    return urldecode($s);
}

add_filter('get_search_query', 'livchem_search_filter');
add_filter('the_search_query', 'livchem_search_filter');

function livchem_query_vars_search_filter($query)
{
    if ($query->is_search && !is_admin()) {
        $query->query_vars['s'] = urldecode($query->query_vars['s']);
    }

    return $query;
}
add_action('parse_query', 'livchem_query_vars_search_filter');
```

As a plus this also works well for path related searches now, so if I added the following to my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} s=(.*)
RewriteRule ^$ /search/%1? [R,L]
```

Searches would be structured like so:  `/search/searchterm`

And the query with special characters also now works.  what a pain in the neck this was to get working properly, for something that is part of the CMS.