# Search is not working in wordpress with special characters

Tags: wordpress, search

I'm trying to search in title and content of the different custom fields.

```
$args = array('exclude_from_search' => array( 'order-request'),
        "post_type" => array('post','document','page','event','product'),
        's' =>  get_search_query()
    );
$context['posts'] = Timber::get_posts($args);
```

But when I search something like *`"Example ' Assistants"`* even when that is the title of a post if I search "Example" the post is there.
How can I include some special characters ?

Comment: I'm not near a working wordpress install to test this for you, but have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42405614/6049581)

Answer (score 0):

The trick is change the default escaped value in true as false.
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_search_query/

```
's' =>  get_search_query(false)
```